# Search bar filter not working for my array item

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I have some arrays, which contains a title, description/notes, and runDate. The table works perfectly but now I am adding in a search bar. However, the filter is not picking anything up it does not offer any pop up options. Trouble line:

```
searchingRuns = runs.filter({$0.title.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
```

Is this because I need to call out the array item not just the array for example: runs.title.filter ... i did try it but it did not work.

```
import UIKit

class RunTableViewController: UITableViewController, RunCellDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    var runs = [Run]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    
    var searchingRuns = [String]()
    var searching = false
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let savedRuns = Run.loadRuns() {
            runs = savedRuns
        }
        
        runs.sort { $0.runDate > $1.runDate}
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
        
        if let savedRuns = Run.loadRuns() {
            runs = savedRuns
        }
        
        runs.sort { $0.runDate > $1.runDate}
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return searchingRuns.count
        } else {
        return runs.count
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RunCellIdentifier") as? RunCell else {
            fatalError("Could not dequeue a cell")
        }
        if searching {
            cell.textLabel?.text = searchingRuns[indexPath.row]
        } else {
        
        cell.delegate = self
        
        let run = runs[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel?.text = run.title
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = run.notes
        cell.dateLabel.text = Run.runDateFormatter.string(from: run.runDate)
        }
       
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        
        runs.sort { $0.runDate > $1.runDate}
        
        return true
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            runs.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            Run.saveRuns(runs)
        }
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
            let runViewController = segue.destination as! RunViewController
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let selectedRun = runs[indexPath.row]
            runViewController.run = selectedRun
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func unwindToRunList(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        guard segue.identifier == "saveUnwind" else { return }
        let sourceViewController = segue.source as! RunViewController
        
        if let run = sourceViewController.run {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                runs[selectedIndexPath.row] = run
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
            } else {
                let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: runs.count, section: 0)
                runs.append(run)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
        
        Run.saveRuns(runs)
        
        if let savedRuns = Run.loadRuns() {
            runs = savedRuns
        }
       
        runs.sort { $0.runDate > $1.runDate}
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func checkmarkTapped(sender: RunCell) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender) {
            let run = runs[indexPath.row]
            runs[indexPath.row] = run
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            Run.saveRuns(runs)
        }
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchingRuns = runs.filter({$0.title.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: The last part with cancellation is wrong because you are not changing your string array.  So there is no point of reloading table.  What you need is two string arrays.  One array contains all strings.  So return this string array when the search field contains no keyword.  And use the other array to filter the first array.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code:

**viewWillAppear/viewDidLoad**

You are loading the runs in both methods, which is redundant.
You do not need to do this in viewDidLoad, because viewWillAppear will be called just after viewDidLoad.

**tableView(_:canEditRowAt:)**
Here, why would you sort your runs again? Remove that line.
Remember: Anytime you change your data source (adding, removing, change ordering), you need to also update the table view

**Filtering**
There is a bunch of `if searching ...` statements in your code, which is hard to maintain, and you can already see that you are missing it in various methods.

The best would be - like @ElTomato wrote - to have two separate arrays, one that holds the "original" data, and one that holds the "filtered" data.

- In your code, you then would almost always work with the filtered data
- when re-loading, -filtering or when cancelling the filter, you re-create the filtered data from the original data. If you are not filtering, they are both the same
- when modifying, you modify the original data and then re-create the filtered data